# Arabic text is getting reversed after setting the text using setter method in java

Tags: java, utf-8

i am trying to display text like this
`a.m 03:00`  i.e., label space time
I am setting the value like this:

```
xyz.setTime(label + " " + time);
```

when i do the logger :
`logger.info(label + " " + time);` i expect to see `a.m 03:00`
but i see `03:00 a.m` as the result. Also the getter method shows the same incorrect value.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Also, reminder that arabic text is written right to left, not left to right. So if your "label" is some arabic text and your "time" is numbers and ":", then the correct way to display the resulting text is right to left. Which means that on the left you have the end of the text, which is the time, and on the right you have the start of the text, which is the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did and it works perfect

```
String timeLabelDetails = "\u202B" + time +"\u202C" +" " +label;
```

`System.out.println(timeLabelDetails);`

gives the result label space time
Example: ‫11:00‬ صباحًا

Answer (score 0):

u can show with date formatter:

```
logger.info(label + " " + new SimpleDateFormat("a hh:mm").format(time))
```